# Web Pages won't load in the Chromium CEF WebBrowser (Winforms)

Tags: winforms, chromium-embedded

I have been using the embedded Winforms WebBrowser but now have an issue with urls where the query string exceeds 2000 characters. I decided to use CefSharp.Winforms to embed Chromium (since it has the support for longer query strings). It works great after following this guide https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application in a standalone project. However, when I try include it in my project (x64) I am unable to load any web pages. It compiles and runs but nothing shows at all.

Has anyone else experienced this? I have tried switching to x86 as well but to no avail. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, posting here for anyone else who might have the same issue:

```
settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = @"x64\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";
Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

Not too sure why I need to specify this or what other issues I might run into down the line but for now it's working perfectly :)